# web2py - setting up my own environment

Tags: python, web2py

I've created a web2py app using the admin interface, but I want to use my own editor and version control. I've downloaded the packed app, but what do I do with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the admin interface to install (i.e., unpack) the app. From that point, the app is just a bunch of files in folders, so you can use any editor, IDE, and version control system on those files as you see fit.